# std::vector::push_back throws segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I've got problem with my program. For small number of edges it works perfectly, but when it gets 15000 edges of oriented graph, i get segmentation fault after one minute runtime. Debugger says that it is thrown by vector push_back method. Do somebody of you know what is wrong with the code and how to avoid it?

Error is thrown in dfs procedure at line **result.push_back(tmpResult);**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int endNode;      // Number of dest node
    bool used;                 // true, if edge was used in dfs
} EdgeType;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int startNode;     // Number of source node
    vector<EdgeType> edge;      // Outgoing edges from node
} NodeType;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int startNode;
    unsigned int endNode;
} ResultType;


bool loadInput(vector<NodeType>& graph, unsigned int& numEdges);
void dfs(vector<NodeType>& graph, unsigned int i, unsigned int numEdges, vector<ResultType>& result);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<NodeType> graph;
    vector<ResultType> result;
    unsigned int numEdges;

    result.reserve(300000);

    // Generate oriented multigraph (3 nodes, 150000 edges)
    numEdges = 150000;
    NodeType tmpNode;
    EdgeType tmpEdge;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        tmpEdge.used = false;
        tmpEdge.endNode = 1;
        tmpNode.edge.push_back(tmpEdge);     
    }
    tmpNode.startNode = 0;
    graph.push_back(tmpNode);
    tmpNode.edge.clear();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        tmpEdge.used = false;
        tmpEdge.endNode = 2;
        tmpNode.edge.push_back(tmpEdge);     
    }
    tmpNode.startNode = 1;
    graph.push_back(tmpNode);
    tmpNode.edge.clear();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        tmpEdge.used = false;
        tmpEdge.endNode = 0;
        tmpNode.edge.push_back(tmpEdge);     
    }
    tmpNode.startNode = 2;
    graph.push_back(tmpNode);
    tmpNode.edge.clear();

    cout << "numEdges: " << numEdges << endl;

    // Find way
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++) {
        dfs(graph, i, numEdges, result);
    }

    // No way found
    cout << "-1" << endl;

    return 0;
}

void dfs(vector<NodeType>& graph, unsigned int i, unsigned int numEdges, vector<ResultType>& result) {
    // Way was found, print it and exit program (bad style, only for testing)
    if (numEdges == result.size()) {
        cout << graph.size() << endl;
        vector<ResultType>::iterator it;
        for (it = result.begin(); it != result.end(); it++) {
            cout << (*it).startNode << " " << (*it).endNode << endl;
        }
        cout << "0 0" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    // For each outgoing edge do recursion 
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < graph[i].edge.size(); j++) {
        if (i >= graph.size()) return;
        if (!graph[i].edge[j].used) {
            graph[i].edge[j].used = true;
            ResultType tmpResult;
            tmpResult.startNode = graph[i].startNode;
            tmpResult.endNode = graph[i].edge[j].endNode;
            result.push_back(tmpResult);
            dfs(graph, graph[i].edge[j].endNode, numEdges, result);
            result.pop_back();
            graph[i].edge[j].used = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The goal for me with my program is to find a way in oriented graph, where each edge is used just once.

Comment: Can't you narrow it down any?

Comment: You shouldn't access vectors using `graph[i]`. It's much safer to use `graph.at(i)` as this will check that the graph is big enough first and will throw an exception if now. The danger with `[i]` is that it might try to access beyond the bounds of the array and corrupt your memory, giving you a seg fault or similar. Some might try to argue that `.at(i)` is slower, but ignore them :-) In a real-world program, your profile will usually confirm this is negligible. Focus on correctness before optimizing.

Comment: @Aaron : Indexing out-of-bounds is a programming error, i.e. a bug. Using `.at()` instead of `operator[]` doesn't fix the bug, it merely makes it manifest differently. The advice should be to actually _fix_ the bug, not to merely throw an exception when the bug is encountered.

Comment: @ildjarn, using `.at` should make it much easier to find the bug. It creates defined behaviour and will help in tracking down the root cause. But `[]` is totally undefined - an out-of-bounds error on one vector might be silently accepted and not cause any problems until a different vector is accessed, causing confusion all round. I'd recommend two steps: First, use `at` by default as it will help to manifest bugs and understand bugs, and second to fix bugs.

Comment: @Aaron : That's what assertions are for -- letting the _programmer_ know there is a bug -- and every standard library I've used has some facility for enabling bounds-checking assertions in debug builds. The user doesn't care how a bug manifests, only that there is one, so making the bug manifest in a more user-friendly way is downright silly. TL;DR: use assertions to handle programming errors, use exceptions to handle user errors.

Comment: @ildjarn, good points. I'm pretty paranoid about assertions too. I think we both agree that the status quo (`[]` without assertions in non-debug build) is wrong :-)

Comment: ... and it's possible to have a typo in the assertion `assert(j>=0 && j<v.size();` when it was meant to be `i`. Personally, I use `.at` (and similar) at all times, and try to include relevant assertions. Laziness is a factor though.

Comment: @Aaron : No, I absolutely do not agree that `operator[]` in non-debug builds is wrong -- if there's no bug, then there's no point in bounds-checking; if there _is_ a bug, then an exception is not the way to handle it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6483/discussion-between-aaron-mcdaid-and-ildjarn)

Answer (score 6):

`dfs` calls itself recursively; increasing `numEdges` increases the recursion depth so, consequently, increasing `numEdges` sufficiently causes a stack overflow (which manifests as a segfault on your platform).

Either build your program with a larger stack size (compiler-specific) or don't use recursion in this scenario.

Comment: +1. Tho could be just out of memory thing, since exception is thrown. When running out of a stack space, it should just die.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: The question says that there's a segmentation fault, not an exception.

Comment: @Vlad : No exception is thrown, the debugger is just incorrectly showing the line _before_ the one that's actually causing the problem (the recursive call to `dfs`).

Comment: Yes, this is it. When i made the stack larger, the program started to work. Now i have to revrite it without recursion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that you're recursing too deeply, causing a stack overflow. On most platforms, the stack has a fixed size; you may be able to make it bigger, but you probably still won't be able to support arbitrarily large graphs.

Perhaps you could replace the recursion with an iterative algorithm, maintaining your own stack (e.g. a `std::stack`) of the state you need to restore when you backtrack. Then the only limit on graph size is the available memory.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you. It is OK with larger stack. I have to rewrite the program without recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If `push_back` throws, it is most likely because your program is running out of memory. Since you do not catch any exceptions, the default exception handler is getting invoked and application is terminated. In gdb, you can use `catch throw` command to stop on every "throw" statement.

Comment: He gets a segfault, there's no actual exception being thrown.

Comment: @ildjarn: Well, OP says "debugger says.... thrown". I cannot imagine GDB says that about signals, as it says something like "Program received signal...".

Comment: The OP actually says "*segmentation fault ... is thrown*", which is clearly nonsensical. ;-]

Comment: Problem solved, thank you. And sorry for my bad explanation. I should not have written that segfault is thrown. It really is nonsence.